# Convert MSSQL paging statement to MySQL paging statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server, pagination, migration

I wish to convert a basic paging MSSQL statement to MySQL.
particularly the ROW_NUMBER() and OVER combined with ORDER BY are tricky to me.

```
SELECT * FROM (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY publishdate DESC) as RowNum,
* FROM news WHERE publishdate <=getdate()) as info
WHERE RowNum > 0 AND RowNum <= (100)
```

How would I convert thisto a MySQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) syntax like this:

```
select * 
FROM news WHERE publishdate <= CURDATE()
LIMIT 0,100; # Retrieve rows 1-100
```

The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```